# Android In-App Billing Item unavailable

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, billing, in-app-billing

I'm implementing in-app billing in Android and it's giving me headaches.

When I try to buy my products from the in-app store, bang: "Item unavailable",
but if I try the `android_test_purchased` everything goes fine.

I made a list with 'all' the possible causes for this problem and checked each one.
Here is the list:

- in `Security.java`, the public key should be same as the one in the Android Market account
- the version of the Market application in the Device should be `2.3.4` or higher
- the device you use for testing must run a standard version of the `Android 1.6` or later
- the application being tested must be uploaded as `draft`, in the Android market, and must be signed
- the application installed in the device must be the same as the one that was uploaded as draft to the market
- the device must have a `something@gmail.com` account as its primary account and this account should be defined as a test account in the Android market
- the products for in-app billing in the Android market must have the same IDs as the ones displayed in the application
- the in-app products in the Android market must be published

Any suggestion and modification to this list is well appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

one more point I like to mention is
The account u are using for test purchases must b mentioned as a test account in your market account

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into same issue. Solution was to wait, it take several hours, perhaps one day, until published items in unpublished app become "online".

Answer (score 0):

I might have the same problem. There seems to be a known issue that test accounts created after August 1st is not working. 
See [Known Purchasing issues from Help pages](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs)

No mention anywhere when this is resolved though..

Comment: I can't see this. Can you KlasE? I hope it means the issue has gone away, and I can rely on just waiting.